# Why can't I store the result of calling a method on a date object in a variable

Tags: javascript, date, object, methods, initialization

This is when I was solving a problem in Beginning Javascript. The task was to display a date 12 months from now.

This seems to work:

```
var dateNow = new Date ();
var currentMonth = dateNow.getMonth();
dateNow.setMonth(currentMonth + 12);
var dateNext = dateNow;
document.write(dateNext.toDateString())
```

While this does not:

```
var dateNow = new Date ();
var currentMonth = dateNow.getMonth();
var dateNext = dateNow.setMonth(currentMonth + 12);
document.write(dateNext.toDateString())
```

Why can't I initialize the variable of dateNext?

Sorry if this seems like an elementary question, I am a week in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how the [setMonth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Date.prototype_Methods) works. It does not return a date but a timestamp - Epoch - an integer of milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

You can do this instead but it will change dateNow

```js
var dateNow = new Date ();
var currentMonth = dateNow.getMonth();
var dateNext = new Date(dateNow.setMonth(currentMonth + 12));
document.write(dateNext.toDateString());
```

This is likely what you want

```js
var dateNow = new Date (); // optional
var dateNext = new Date();
dateNext.setMonth(dateNext.getMonth() + 12);
document.write(dateNext.toDateString());
```

Comment: Thank you so much :). That really clarifies things.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of the setMonth() method is the number of milliseconds between the date object and midnight January 1 1970. toDateString() is a method of Date, so it doesn't work if you call it on a number, which is what your second snippet is setting dateNext to.

Comment: Oh thank you so much for the clarification. Yup I just checked
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setmonth.asp
Indeed when I write dateNext, I get the timestamps..

Comment: This is a much better reference than w3schools: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date